Azure Function app on Premium App service plan P2V3
I am trying to understand how this functionality works and the costing involved. We currently have a premium App service plan P3V3 and I wanted to leverage this plan to deploy a new Azure function app. Looking at the pricing calculator on Azure portal, There is no option to select this App service plan and it only displays Elastic Premium plans and also all their documenation only mentions about Elastic plans with no mention about Premium plans.
I would like to use the existing app plan and deploy function app with Always on feature disabled.
Can you please point me to any documentation that provides costing and understanding on how this setup works.
Thanks.

Premium function app plane and App service plan both are different. If you are choosing App service plan then you will have Always On option but Premium function app plan doesn't comes with Always on option

Can you share the screenshot of the plan you are selecting while creating the function app?

In order to choose a specific pricing plan, select App Service hosting plan which comes with multiple pricing plan options like P2V2, P2V3 etc.

To know more about the different pricing plans, click on Explore pricing plans option.

You can select the pricing plan as per your need from the available list.

Once the function app is created then you can disable the Always On option by navigating to Configuration -> General Settings if you don't need it.


Thanks @IkthesamAfrin : I have realized based on above comment we cant disable Always On in the Premium plans of EP1..EP3. I have followed the same process you have mentioned and unfortunately in the pricing calculator of Azure, we cant select App service plan from the drop down under Function App i.e it only provides option to select Premium plan(EP1..EP3), it would be nice to have this selection in single line item under function app, instead of explaining to business folks.

I am not getting you, can you share some screenshots of how you are doing this?

@user25922076 Did you get the correct plan as per your requirement?

From analysis we are going with "App Service plan" option(the one you have rightly chosen above), as we do have few plans that are available to consume due to low usage pattern.

There is a fundamental difference between Azure Function Plans and App Service Plans.
To explain this, we currently have multiple options to host Azure Functions:
Serverless

Consumption Function Plans
Premium Function Plans
Flex-Consumption Plans

App Service based

App Service Plans
App Service Environments

Kubernetes

Azure ARC enabled Kubernetes
Functions on Container Apps

Every of those options comes with different features and costs. But we can break them down in those 3 categories above.
When you want the most Function and Serverless like features, you should go with the "Serverless" group. There is a good comparison in the docs when to use what.
For the pricing, please see the pricing pages for functions, app service, container apps
There is some documentation regarding deploying on App Service Plans. However, I'd recommend you to use the "Serverless" options, which provide more features and you do not need to setup scaling rules by yourself. Maybe even consumption is an option for you, which brings also pricing benefits for infrequent called functions.
If you want to shed more light on your requirements, we can talk what plan is the best option for you.
